# Driver for shared network printer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, network-printer

I have a printer installed on Windows XP PC and this PC also connects to a network that all other clients have Windows 7.

Do I have to install Windows 7 driver of this printer on XP PC to have access to this shared printer or not?

I can ping XP PC from other clients and also have access to its shared folders, but I can't
access to shared printer and I guess that's because of driver issue.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not given details on the brand or model of printer, so this answer is very general, but should give you a good idea what to do to install the printer. Sometimes the manufacture's website will have instructions how to do this for their specific equipment.

The easiest way to do this is to use the "Add Printer" wizard in Windows 7. From the Windows button, choose `Devices and Printers`. In the window that opens, choose `Add Printer` from the top of the window.

[image]

Choose `Add a network, bluetooth or wireless printer`. This will bring up a window of printers found on the network. Choose the printer you want then click Next. This will search for the drivers and if they aren't installed you will be prompted to install them. There are a lot of printer drivers already available within Windows 7, so you may not have to find the drivers yourself.

If the printer is not listed, click the `The printer that I want isn't listed`

[image]

Since you said you "I can ping XP PC", choose the option to `Add printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname`. Follow the prompts from there.

In the event the drivers aren't found, you may have to download them from the manufacturer's website.